# VBscript error code 800A0046 permission denied

Tags: vbscript, permissions, network-programming

I am currently trying to create a script that does a bit of remote scripting that triggers a simple messagebox to appear on the screen of a remote user to let a user on a domain network alert every other user that there is a threat in the building. I run the script that is supposed to send the warning to every other users but I get the above mentioned error.

Line: 9
Char: 2
Error: Permission denied
Code: 800A0046

I have tried locating the script in a public network share folder so all users can reach it and have highest permissions to reach it.

I have tested to make sure they can read the pclist file which is just a file with the computer name of every computer in the building that needs to alert.

```
Dim oFSO, oTSin, oController, oRemote, sComputer
Set oController = CreateObject ("WSHController")
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set oTSin = oFSO.OpenTextFile("I:\Public\PCLIST.txt") 'List of PC's

Do Until oTSin.AtEndOfStream
 sComputer = oTSin.ReadLine
 'Location of script to make run below between ""
 Set oRemote = oController.CreateScript("I:\Public\VBS\Alert.vbs", sComputer)
 oRemote.Execute

WScript.Echo "Finished script on " & sComputer

Loop
oTSin.Close
WScript.Echo "Finished all computers"
```

As state above all I really want is just a remote messagebox and maybe a echo char 7 to play over every users computer from like a panic button script. If there is a better way someone please let me know.

Comment: I believe that the user account that the vbscript is running under _must_ have administrator privileges on any workstation that you wish to pop up the message - and even then, I'm not certain it will work. You may want to think about a client/server messaging model instead.

Comment: I followed up with a friend who wrote something similar to this turns out that the WSHController is limited and does not allow for UI and will not allow a popup box or echoes which the script I had(Alert.vbs) was using both of. You are right I might have to setup a client/server model instead of peer to peer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.repairwin.com/fixed-permission-denied-800a0046-windows-script-host/

This is a typical error when you try to run a program on a remote computer. It is due to the permissions you have on those machines. You must be administrator of all, even if you are fail many times.
  What I do is to send through the Languard application a rar auto-run file to all the machines. 
I explain the file you want to run on each machine I send it in rar format but auto-run. When it arrives at that machine the autorun opens giving way to the autorun of for example yours, Alert.vbs
 I don't know how to send you here a file, or your Alert.vbs file in rar-exe format.

Comment: this work in win7, but not in win10